# Can't use ref in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-ref

I created a react component with an input and wanted to pass a ref and some other props to it, but it gives an error I created a react component with an input and wanted to pass a ref and some other props to it, but it gives an error

> Type '{ ref: RefObject; type: string; placeholder: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes'.
> Property 'type' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes'.

code:

```
...
MyInput.jsx
...
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react'
import classes from './MyInput.module.css'

const MyInput = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    return (
        <input ref={ref} className={classes.myInput} {...props} />
    );
});

export default MyInput;
...
App.js
...
const bodyInputRef = React.createRef()
...
<MyInput 
    ref={bodyInputRef} 
    type="text" 
    placeholder='Post body
/>
```

Comment: Try `useRef()` instead of `createRef`

Comment: already tried it unfortunately doesn't work

Comment: Are you using TypeScript? If so you should type your `forwardRef`